# Can't import model on openvino DL workbench

Tags: intel, workbench, openvino

I need to accelerate my onnx model on CPU. I'm using Mac OS Big Sur. I downloaded DL workbench via docker:

```
➜  ~ git:(main) ✗ docker pull openvino/workbench:2021.4
➜  ~ git:(main) ✗ docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5665:5665 --name workbench -it openvino/workbench:2021.4
```

Then it has written: *DL Workbench is available at http://127.0.0.1:5665/.* I opened it, created a project.  And when I tried to import my onnx model, it stopped. I waited for 15 minutes - still the same. The DL workbench sees my CPU and it's available. Then I checked what is going on in terminal, and there was:

```
[E:] [BSL] found 0 ioexpander device
E: [xLinkUsb] [    566474] [gunicorn] usb_find_device_with_bcd:266  Library has not been initialized when loaded
```

I think problem is here, but don't know how to solve it and can't find anything in google. Does anybody face with it?

UPD: I also tried import existing models from models zoo, but unlucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in a wrong browser, I used Safari. When I changed browser to Chrome importing become work.

Answer (score 2):

The model uploading stuck issue is related to the Safari browser, please move to the Google Chrome browser as this is the [recommended browser for DL Workbench](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/workbench_docs_Workbench_DG_Prerequisites.html#recommended).